# React DateTime picker with the milliseconds option

Tags: reactjs, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am trying to find a DateTime picker with milliseconds option. The recommended format would be 'yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss.msmsms'. Is there any DateTime component where I can adjust this type of format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Datepicker or Rangepicker in a special format with micro-second like `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.SSS`